# Define a protocol type variable in another protocol

Tags: swift, protocols, associated-types

I want to define a variable **v1** of type protocol **p1** in some other protocol **p3** , and in class **c1** which conform to protocol **p3** i want to define **v1** from a another protocol **p2** which is a child of **p1**.

in a normal way i got this error

> Type 'c1' does not conform to protocol 'p3'

do you have any solution ?

```
protocol p1 {}

protocol p2: p1 {}

protocol p3 {
    var del: p1! { get set }
}

class c1: p3 {
    var del: p2!
}
```

Comment: Before anything else, this violates the [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: [Why do you want to do this?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Im using VIP architecture and i have a vipViewController protocol which have interactor variable that is a type of business logic protocol. I want to define interactor in each viewController of specific business logic protocol. @Sweeper

Answer (score 1):

You can’t do this.

You define protocol `p2` to conform to protocol `p1`.

You define protocol `p3`’s member `del` to confirm to protocol `p1`.

You define class `c1` to conform to protocol `p3`, and its member `del` to conform to `p2`.

Here’s the issue: if class `c1` conforms to protocol `p3`, then you should be able to assign anything that conforms to protocol `p1` to its `del` member. That’s what conforming to protocol `p1` means, as you yourself have defined it.

*But* you have defined class `c1`’s `del` member to conform to protocol `p2`. This is the problem.

This does work one way – anything conforming to protocol `p2` is known to also conform to protocol `p1`, so you can assign anything conforming to protocol `p2` to an instance of class `c1`’s member `del` and it will be fine.

However it doesn’t work the other way. Things conforming to protocol `p1` aren’t defined to conform to protocol `p2`. So we have a gap. Because class `c1` conforms to protocol `p3`, you *should* be able to assign something that doesn’t conform to protocol `p2` – but does conform to protocol `p1` – to its member `del`. That’s the way you’ve defined the protocol. But you’ve *also* defined `c1`’s `del` to conform to protocol `p2`.

You’re telling the type system two different things. You’re saying that `del` requires something that’s `p1` indirectly through the protocol, and you’re saying that `del` requires something that’s `p2` directly through the class definition. Both can’t be true, so the compiler can’t proceed.